# Firestore Listeners for python

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I want to know a way to listen to any changes that happen in a document in Firestore like adding a new document or deleting a document. But I can't find any relevant documentation regarding this matter so please if anyone used this before post the code snippets to help me.

To overcome this problem I have made an infinite loop to check if there are any changes every second but after about 15 minutes if gets me an error too many requests

**Edit**

After using the On snapshot listener my application just doesn't do anything it just runs with no errors and then terminates and below the code, I have used.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import firestore , credentials

cred = credentials.Certificate("AdminSDK.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()


def on_snapshot(col_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    print(u'Callback received query snapshot.')
    print(u'Current cities in California: ')
    for change in changes:
        if change.type.name == 'ADDED':
            print(u'New city: {}'.format(change.document.id))
        elif change.type.name == 'MODIFIED':
            print(u'Modified city: {}'.format(change.document.id))
        elif change.type.name == 'REMOVED':
            print(u'Removed city: {}'.format(change.document.id))
col_query = db.collection(u'NeedClassification')
query_watch = col_query.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)
```

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection If you're having trouble making that work, edit your question to include the [minimum, complete/standalone code that reproduces the problem.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue and the root cause for me was that I didn't get the script to keep running by adding this at the end:

```
while True:
time.sleep(1)
print('processing...')
```

For reference my entire code and output is:

```
import firebase_admin
import google.cloud
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore
import time

print('Initializing Firestore connection...')
# Credentials and Firebase App initialization. Always required
firCredentials = credentials.Certificate("./key.json")
firApp = firebase_admin.initialize_app (firCredentials)

# Get access to Firestore
db = firestore.client()
print('Connection initialized')

def on_snapshot(doc_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    for doc in doc_snapshot:
        print(u'Received document snapshot: {}'.format(doc.id))

doc_ref = db.collection('audio').document('filename')
doc_watch = doc_ref.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)

# Keep the app running
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print('processing...')
```

Output (before adding the loop the output stops at Connection initialized):

```
Initializing Firestore connection...
Connection initialized
Received document snapshot: filename
processing...
processing...
processing...
processing...
processing...
processing...
Received document snapshot: filename
processing...
processing...
# ...[and so on]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do i listen to only on_create and get inserted document's data?

Comment: I tried your solution but it used a lot of network so I used node JS API to listen to the changes and when it find change it spawn a python process and pass the document ID as a parm so that python file do whatever it wants with it

Comment: It's not supposed to use a lot of network as firestore architecture should avoid it. How do oy tested it? @MohamedNashaat

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer @ecdemomaniaKay, I was having the same problem. Do you now if there's a way to wait the first snapshot and then continues the code?

Comment: Is there a way to print what exact;y has changed?